# Committed before 401 No authentication specified

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets

I'm programming using GWT, which includes Jetty. I have defined my own servlet and when I call

`response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());`

It gives me a warning that states: 
`WARNING: Committed before 401 No authentication specified
Sep 2, 2009 2:40:36 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:990)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:238)`

Does anyone know what this means? Am I supposed to do something before I call sendError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was called `super.doPost(req, resp);`as the first thing I did. This caused the error when I tried to send an error or write to the HttpServletResponse object.

Comment: Could you accept your own answer so this doesn't show up in the Unanswered feed anymore?